# inequality involving expectation of the maximum

Tags: probability, expectation, order-statistics

For $X_i \sim$ i.i.d with cdf $F_x$, and $\forall c \in \mathbb R$, then, letting $M_n$ denote the maximum observation

$$
M_n \le c+  \sum_i^n (X_i - c) \mathbb I(X_i > c)
$$
I proved this by taking $n=1$ and $X_i = c$ and showing that this was a contradiction. Now, I am trying to show that, for $\bar{F}(x)= 1- F(x)$ :

$$
E(M_n) \le c + n \int_c^\infty \bar{F}(x)dx
$$
My attempt so far, using the initial result, then then the same inequality must hold for the expectations of both sides, that is:
\begin{align*}
E(M_n) &\le c+  \sum_i^n E[(X_i - c) \mathbb I(X_i > c)] \\
&\overset{\text{iid}}{=}c+ n E[(X - c) \mathbb I(X > c)] \\
&= c+ n \int_{-\infty}^ \infty (x-c)\mathbb I(X > c) f_X(x) dx \\
&= c+ n \int_{c}^ \infty (x-c)  f_X(x) dx \\
&= c+ n \int_{c}^ \infty x  f_X(x) dx - nc \int_c^\infty f_X(x)dx \\
&=c+ n \int_{c}^ \infty x  f_X(x) dx -nc \bar{F}(c)\\
\end{align*}

I think i take a wrong turn somewhere, maybe I shouldn't expand the term in the integral, I still don't quite get where the second integral would come from, to define the CDF in the required inequality... any hints?

Comment: You are probably actually trying to show that $$
E(M_n) \le c + \color{red}{n}\int_c^\infty \bar{F}(x)dx,
$$ which seems direct from the pointwise inequality above, since $$E((X-c);X>c)=\int_c^\infty \bar{F}(x)dx.
$$

Comment: @Did, yes, my mistake, edited now. Is it a conditional expectation in your second line ?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did  then what is ; ??

Comment: As is rather universally used, E(X;A)=E(X.I(A)).

Comment: @Did I guess my question is then how do we prove that statement? I would still get stuck at the same point as I do in my question

Comment: Integrate both sides of the identity $$(x-c)I(x>c)=\int_c^\infty I(t<x)dt$$ with respect to the distribution $P_X$ of $X$ (which will automatically give the *corrected* version of the identity that you need).

Comment: @Did Thanks! That makes sense now